# elastic search - how to query the child resource

Tags: elasticsearch, resources, sense

I have a resource

```
GET /parents/{Id}
```

this one I can see the alias in elastic search, I am able to retrieve data in ES by doing this : `(GET parents_alias/parent/5/)`

However with this resource
2/
For `/parents/{Id}/comment/{commentId}` I do not have an alias
I do not know how to query in ES in order to get comment

any idea?

Comment: What is the index name and paretn type and child type here ? Can you share your parent child mapping for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a parent child association in elasticsearch I believe you need to first create the parent-child mapping as explained here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child-mapping.html

Also you can get parent records if you know child details and vice versa.
More details here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/has-child.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/has-parent.html